# Stream processing from a specific offset to an end offset

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is it possible to do kafka stream processing from a specific offset of input topic to an end offset?

I have one Kafka stream application which consume an input topic but for some reason it failed. I fixed the issue and started it again but it started consuming from the latest offset of the input topic. I know the offset of the input topic till which the application has processed. Now, how can I process the input topic from one offset to another. I am using confluent Platform 5.1.2.

Answer (score 2):

By default, KStreams supports two possible values for `auto.offset.reset`. It could be either "**earliest**" or "**latest**". You can't set it to a specific offset in your application code.

There is an option during the application reset. If you use application reset script, you can use the `--to-offset` property and assign it to the specific offset. It will reset the application to that point.

```
<path-to-confluent>/bin/kafka-streams-application-reset --application-id app1 --input-topics a,b --to-offset 1000
```

You can find the details in the documentation :
https://docs.confluent.io/5.1.2/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html

In case, if you are fixing the bugs, it will be better to reset to the earliest state if possible.

Comment: Thanks Nishu, but I used --reset-offsets of kafka-consumer-groups and executed the application again which started from the specified offset. eg: `kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <ip>:<port> --group my-group --topic input-topic:partition-no --reset-offsets --to-offset <offset-no>`